# How many ways are there of choosing $n_1$ from $N_1$ through $n_k$ from $N_k$ objects?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Problem:** How many ways are there of choosing $n_1$ objects of the first kind, $n_2$ objects of the second kind, and so forth, to $n_k$ objects of the $k^{th}$ kind, where there are altogether $N_1$ objects of the first kind, $N_2$ objects of the second kind, and so on? How many ways are there if $n_i$ is greater than $N_i$ for some $i$?

I came across this problem and I'm entirely new to this topic. I'm honestly pretty confused what the question is asking for and how to start answering/solving it.
From what I think I understand it's saying

$${n_1 \choose N_1} + {n_2 \choose N_2} +  \dotsb +{n_k \choose N_k}. $$

And how many ways if $n_i$ is greater than $N_i$?  (isn't this impossible?)

Am I misunderstanding the question entirely? And how would I get started?

Comment: If you have three balls and are asked to choose five of them, how many ways can you do this?  As you note, this appears to be impossible, hence there are no ways of doing this, thus the convention is that $\binom{N}{k} = 0$ when $k > N$.

Comment: Also, your binomial coefficients seem to be reversed.  $$\binom{n}{k}$$ is the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects out of a total of $n$ objects.  This is typically read "$n$ choose $k$", which might be expanded to "from a collection of $n$ objects, choose $k$ of those objects."  Specify the size of the total collection first, then the number of objects to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{N_i}{n_i}$ ways to choose $n_i$ objects out of $N_i$.

So there are: $$\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N_i}{n_i}$$ways to do that for $i=1,2,\dots,k$.

This under the convention that $\binom{N_i}{n_i}=0$ if $n_i\notin\{0,1,\dots,N_i\}$, so that the answer is $0$ if $n_i>N_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$.